# PHP Redirect To URL Variable

Tags: php, html, variables, redirect

I'm trying to make a redirect page that when you access www.website.com/redirect.php?link=http://example.com, in a few seconds your browser would redirect to example.com after you are shown a redirect disclaimer. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the target link NEED to be a get parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript works, but you don't need it, just use meta refresh

```
<?php 

$url=$_GET['link'];

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rediercting</title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL='<?php echo $url; ?>'" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">Redirecting to <?php echo $url; ?></a></p>
        <p>Some disclaimer</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch! This answer is best, because it does not require Javascript (in case it's disabled) and is SEO-friendly.

Comment: Just a note of clarification: the `10;` before the URL is the number of seconds until refreshing. Change it as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
    echo "disclaimer here";
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function() { location.href = '<?php echo $_GET["link"]; ?>'; }, 3000);
    </script>';
```

Comment: Why <?php echo disclaimer ?> instead of just having the disclaimer there like you just have <script>...

Comment: Disagreed. It's certainly helpful and a viable solution, but the META tag is better.

Comment: How can you justify "better"? "Better" is such a blanket statement; a lot of the time javascript is the way to go. Also, the meta tag is becoming less and less used and javascript is being more and more SEO friendly in this day and age.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server-side script, so you won't be able to redirect after a delay (as this will occur after the page has loaded, so it's in the hands of the client to handle the redirect at that point).

Try using a page that looks somewhat like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function delayer(){
                window.location = "<?php echo $_GET['link']; ?>"
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="setTimeout('delayer()', 5000)">
        Some info about the redirect!
    </body>
</html>
```

There are three main components here:

1) The JavaScript: The function `delayer()` is called after 5 seconds.

2) The PHP: This inserts the `GET` parameter `link` into the JavaScript function.

3) The HTML: This is where you can insert the disclaimer, where the code says "Some info about the redirect!", in standard HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do this via JavaScript to get a disclaimer message first.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Redirect</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect(){
        window.location = "<?php echo $link; ?>";
    }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="setTimeout(redirect(), 5000);">
  <B>DISCLAIMER HERE</B>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As already said by username tbd you can't delay a redirect on the server side.

Alternative to the JavaScript solution would be native HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15; url=<?php echo $redirectTarget; ?>">
    </head>
    <body>
         Your disclaimer
    </body>
<html>
```

15 indicates the time in seconds to wait before the redirect is done.