# Can I make a Facebook app simply link to another page?

Tags: facebook, hyperlink

I want to try and add a app to my book's page to either link directly to, say, the book's page on Amazon, or (2nd best option) to link to the book's "where to buy this book" facebook page.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a simple example](http://blog.apnafundaz.com/2009/08/facebook-hello-world-application/) to make a link to a PHP script, there you can use [meta refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546297/php-redirect-to-url-variable) to refresh in the page you want to link

Comment: Many, many thanks - it does seem odd that it's so hard to do (i.e. requiring a whole dedicated app).

Comment: If you just want a shortcut for you, you can use an already made app, like: [This tool](http://tech-wonders.blogspot.mx/2011/03/add-link-app-creates-direct-link-in.html)